# Open another terminal from the current one

Tags: terminal

I am working on `Terminal` and attempt to create a New one with commands

```
$  open -a terminal
```

No feedbacks from the command

```
$ open -an terminal
The file ~/terminal does not exist.
```

How to accomplish it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to separate the options and favor -n:

```
open -n -a terminal
```

This creates a 2nd Terminal instance!

If you add another option -F (fresh) you won't see any old/restored sessions:

```
open -n -F -a terminal
```

Comment: interesting, this appears to launch another instance of Terminal.app as compared to using `cmd+n` from an active instance, i.e. just opening another console window. The former can be scrolled through with `cmd+TAB` and the latter `cmd+~`